# How I can use emplace for unordered_set that holds shared_ptr to the object?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, unordered-set

Say I have an object:

```
struct Foo {
    Foo(const std::string& str1, const std::string& str1) 
        : mStr1(str1), mStr2(str2)
    {}

    std::string mStr1;
    std::string mStr2;
};
```

And set

```
typedef std::unordered_set<std::shared_ptr<Foo> , Hash, Compare> Set;
```

I have custom hasher and compare. But when I say:

```
Set set;
set.emplace(str1, str2);
```

I receive compile error, because the constructor of `Foo` is obviously not a constructor of `std::shared_ptr<Foo>`. What I would like is when emplace needs to construct a pointer to use `std::make_shared<Foo>(str1, str2)`

It seems that I also need a custom allocator for that, but I did not manage to implement one that satisfy the compiler.

My question is: Is what I want possible. If yes, how - is the allocator the right way to go. If yes, can you point me to an example.

Comment: Why not just do `set.emplace(std::make_shared(str1, str2));`?

Comment: @zenith This is what I do now, but this already creates an object that will be thrown away if not needed.

Comment: `emplace` always constructs the object anyway, because it can't hash a bunch of constructor arguments or compare them with an existing object for equality. It's worse, even, because it has to construct the object at its final destination, and so always performs a dynamic allocation.

Comment: I thought it will pass the arguments to the hasher and the compare.

Comment: No, the hasher is only required to hash the key type, and the comparator is only required to compare the key type.

Comment: @T.C. How, this even works. If it needs an object to get the hash, how it could construct it at the right place. Isn't this the chicken and the egg problem.

Comment: All the associative/unordered associative containers are node-based. You allocate memory for a node, construct the object in there, get the hash and figure out where the node should go, and link the node in (or throw it away if it's a duplicate and you are unique-key).

Comment: It works by *you pass in an object directly to emplace*. That's the object that gets hashed/compared. Then after that is done, and the location is found, and the set knows whether to insert or not, it constructs the stuff in the place.

Comment: An `is_transparent` hasher that must non-destructively accept anything emplace takes would be interesting.

Comment: @Yakk is this in c++14 or you commenting that it could be done at some point?

Comment: @gsf there is no support for transparent hashers in C++ that I know of.  There is support for transparent comparators for ordered associative containers, but it only supports one-arg on the "other side", not a cluster of args.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `set.insert(std::make_shared<Foo>(str1, str2));`. `emplace` is generally not a gain for container with unique keys when duplicate keys are an issue, because of the way it operates:

- It must construct the object first before it can compare it to existing keys in the container to determine if it can be inserted.
- Once the object is constructed, it cannot be copied or moved, because the object is not required to be copyable or movable. Moreover, there's no reliable way for `emplace` to detect when it *can* copy or move something, because there are plenty of types for which `is_copy_constructible` returns `true` but cannot be actually copied.
- Object construction can only happen once, since the constructor may move from the arguments or have other side effects.

A typical implementation of `emplace` thus always allocates memory for the node up-front, constructs the object inside that memory, compares it with existing elements in the container, and then either links it in, or destroys it and deallocates the memory.

`insert`, on the other hand, has the key readily available. It can therefore first decide whether the node should be inserted, and only allocate memory if it should be.

In theory, implementations might special-case `emplace` for the "one argument with the same type as the element type" case. But I know of no implementation that actually does this.

Answer (score 0):

> I receive compile error, because the constructor of Foo is obviously
>   not a constructor of std::shared_ptr. What I would like is when
>   emplace needs to construct a pointer to use
>   std::make_shared(str1, str2)

`emplace` is implemented as a function that uses perfect forwarding to invoke the constructor of the contained element (in this case shared_ptr). The contained element's constructor accepts a pointer to Foo, therefore you should be able to do this (just like you would construct a `shared_ptr<Foo>` object):

```
set.emplace(new Foo("x", "y")); //or
set.emplace(new Foo(str1, str2));
```

> It seems that I also need a custom allocator for that, but I did not
>   manage to implement one that satisfy the compiler.

A custom allocator is a total overkill if all you want to do is add a shared_ptr in the most efficient way (by invoking forwarding constructor on some pre-allocate element), or I'm totally misunderstanding your question. You would typically use the allocator if you don't want the element to be constructed using the default allocator (which use operator new). In this case, shared_ptr itself will be the element that will be constructed on the heap. You would only use an allocator if you are concerned that heap allocations are for some reason inefficient for your purposes (e.g if you allocate millions of small objects).

Note (as commented by @Yakk) that, in this case it is possible that the instantiation of shared_ptr may throw (I can only think of bad_alloc as possibility), in which case the pointer passed to emplace would cause a leak. For this reason I too think std::make_shared would be a better option (as mentioned in another answer).

Comment: Shared ptr ctor from pointer can throw.  Passing a raw `new` can thus leak, as it is impossibke (almost) to deallocate if the emplace construction of the shared ptr throws.  Not all that important (as a throwing shared otr ctor is an extreme case), but...

Comment: @Yakk. Granted. Nevertheless, what I've stated about emplace holds. I can see that it's not a good idea for smart pointers (considering new doesn't throw, but shared_ptr does), but I've wanted to give the OP an idea of what emplace does. I'll edit my post to indicated std::make_shared to be the better option, but I do think it has some value.

Comment: @Yakk That's not the problem - `shared_ptr`'s constructor is specified to delete the pointer when it throws. The problem is that the container may need to allocate memory *before* it even attempts to construct the `shared_ptr`, and that can throw.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `std::make_shared` directly in the argument list of `emplace`.

`set.emplace(std::make_shared<Foo>(str1, str2));`

No custom allocator required.

Comment: Thank you. This is correct, but it does not answer the question. I assume - you answer is "No, you cannot avoid constructing object", but Yakk's comment makes me thinking that I actually might be.